# Vuejs component not generating list on v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've got a component that needs to render a list. However, every way I try it gives me some version of this error:

> Property or method "messages" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

**code:**

```
Vue.component("vue-home-messages", {
    props: ["user"],
    methods: {
        onClick: function(event, blah) {
            console.log("CLICK: ", event);
            console.log("Blah: ", blah);
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            messages: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    sender: {
                        id: 234,
                        name: "Bob Barker"
                    },
                    subject: "Everything is AWESOME!",
                    body: "Etiam vel nisl ipsum."
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    sender: {
                        id: 234,
                        name: "Bob Barker"
                    },
                    subject: "Maybe Not",
                    body: "Etiam vel nisl ipsum."
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="card border-info mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem; margin: auto;">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">New Messages</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a v-for:"message in messages" 
                            href="#" 
                            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
                            @click="onClick">
                            {{ message.sender }} - {{ message.subject }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change v-for:"message in messages" to v-for="message in messages"

Comment: *facepalm*  How did I miss that for the last hour?  Thanks.